# LDAP is being used instead of LDAPS

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

Due to microsoft enabling channel binding and signing on LDAP on march 10 this year (as explained here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4520412/2020-ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirements-for-windows) I am currently trying to figure out if the code we have needs to be altered to facilitate this change. I currently have this bit of code

```
        var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username);

        if (userPrincipal == null)
            return null;

        var underlyingObject = userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
        if (underlyingObject == null)
            return null;

        PropertyValueCollection homedirProperty = underlyingObject.Properties["HomeDirectory"];
        if (homedirProperty == null || homedirProperty.Value == null)
            return null;

        return homedirProperty.Value as string;
```

from the looks of it this should work with the patch change, but during a test in an environment where this change was enabled it just used the normal LDAP. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to AD using LDAPS instead of LDAP, just specify port 636 in the LDAP path to your domain like so:

```
LDAP://DC=YOURINTERNAL,DC=DOMAIN:636
```

We have our domain path stored in the appsettings.json or web.config for our apps.

Comment: More like: LDAPS://DC=YOURINTERNAL,DC=DOMAIN:636

Comment: @jwilleke Not so, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34862777/11114097