# How to reach LDAP authentication serveur with secured connection (LDAPS)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ldap

We are basically using this line of code to authenticate and/or retrieve informations from LDAP serveur in our web solutions:

```
DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry( "LDAP://SRV-auth-01.adnav.qc.ca:636"  /*db.getLDAP()*/, user + "@adnav.qc.ca", password);
```

Is this a secured connection? One of my coworkers was worried that if we use this it wouldn't be totally safe, not as safe as if we managed to use put an S at the end of `LDAP` like so `"LDAPS://SRV-auth-01.adnav.qc.ca:636"`

it is working without the S though... Has someone ever managed to use an `LDAPS` connection with `DirectoryEntry` class?

related : [How to connect to Active Directory via LDAPS in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34813550/how-to-connect-to-active-directory-via-ldaps-in-c)

Comment: 636 is a ssl only port, if this work using only [LDAP://SRV-aut...] then its a ldaps conneciton., and thus the prefix ldap:// isnt used anyway

Comment: So your saying, if I use port 636 it's an LDAPS connection anyway ?

Comment: yes, you cant communicate using ssl with port 389 and you have to use ssl with port 636

Comment: Alright then, feel free to make it an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

636 is a ssl only port, if this works using only "LDAP://SRV-auth-01.adnav.qc.ca:636" then it's an ssl connection, and thus the prefix "ldap://" isn't used anyway.